# Tag filtering broken?

Tags: bug, tags, search, new-nav

I just tried to do a search for one tag, excluding another, but couldn't get the results I expected. I was wondering if it was broken, or if I was just making a mistake.

As an example, I tried searching for `[java] -[javascript]`, expecting every post tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and not with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). Instead I get zero results. Trying the same search again returns 9.3 million results, many tagged with neither of the tags. Yet at the top I still see this as my search parameters:

> [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) not [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

Since it selected `any` for the tag filter type, I assumed it must be finding anything tagged as Java, or not tagged as Javascript. But if I select `all`, it changes the filter to

> [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

and returns anything tagged as both.

So have I just forgotten how to correctly exclude a tag from a search, or is this a bug?

Comment: [MSE duplicate for new-nav](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259915/hard-to-exclude-tags-in-search-for-new-nav)

Comment: But yes, tag only filtering is broken.  Try adding additional search criteria like `is:question`.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Started a small bounty on your MSE question.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Glad there's a workaround. It's kind of disheartening that you reported this three months ago, and there's no fix yet.

Comment: @Deduplicator thanks.  It never occurred to me to start one of my own.  Although I probably could now on MSE since I'm comfortably over 125 rep there...